# Java Thread : Query regarding Thread waiting state

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

Suppose i have one synchronized block , and say 1000 threads access to that block simultaneously and one thread got access to sync block. Other 999 threads will go to waiting state till they are notified.
I want to know where exactly these 999 threads resides in waiting state. Which data structure is used to hold these 999 threads during waiting state and as soon as they are notified , how one thread is selected by jvm to get access to sync block.
Also any best article that covers thread synchronization and thread monitor. I googled it out but still confused how synchronization actually works internally.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, that's unspecified, and probably depends on the VM and OS. You can't rely on any specific order.

Comment: If you care about order use a fair lock e.g. [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) in fair mode. It guarantees that the longest-waiting thread gets access.

Answer (score 1):

In java threads are [user level threads](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/mtintro-54820/index.html). Unlike Kernel level threads these are managed by the client side library. This library takes care of handling the states of these threads. For example even if 10 threads out of your 1000 threads are processing on 10 different resources and 1 of the thread makes a system call then all the threads(of that process) are blocked with respect to the kernel. However for the user library only the one thread which made the system call is blocked while others are in running state.

Also there is no guarantee which thread will be acquire the next lock. If you want fairness you can use [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) which provides for more functionality than synchronized block. Also it has an optional fairness paramether which if set to true will provide lock to the thread who has waited the longest.

Comment: Even I had asked a similar question on SO. You see thread scheduling is done by OS so there is not much really we can do. JLS says if two threads are waiting for a same resource the one with higher priority will execute first and if they are of the same priority execution will go RR(Round Robin).

Comment: Ya. You are right. But what data structure is used to store waiting thread. Definitely not queue.

Comment: Also if possible kindly provide some best and simple video lecture link or tutorial on how synchronization works internally. I still have confusion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by DS used to store waiting threads. Waiting thread is simply a tread waiting for CPU for a paricular resource. It will not get it unless a processing thread releases it's lock on the resource. If you mean thread DS then as far as Linux is considered a thread has same DS as that of a process(both use clone() syscall).Difference being threads belonging to same process use same process address space. If you mean how threads are accounted for than kernel maintains a thread table(just like process table) where all information(register,state etc) about the threads is kept.